# Can't link an img to an article in blogger

Tags: hyperlink, blogger

I'm not a professional in programming and I need help linking an img to a article in my blog. I know this should be pretty straight-forward but it keeps opening the image instead of opening the article. It keeps opening the scr instead of opening the link in href.

Could anyone help?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example in order to receive help

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much straight forward. Just Upload an image and then select that image, click on the anchor icon and replace the image URL to the one you want to be redirected.

Screenshot for clarification:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with HTML Code:

```
<a href="https://example.com">
<img src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/some-gibberish-text-asdasd-asd" alt="Image Description">
</a>
```

change the URL `https://example.com` with your own url.